# Is there a difference between \d and \d+?

Tags: javascript, regex

https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/find-numbers-with-regular-expressions

I was doing a lesson in FCC, and they mentioned that the digit selector \d finds one digit and adding a + (\d+) in front of the selector allows it to search for more than one digit.

I experimented with it a bit, and noticed that its the g right after the expression that searches for every number, not the +. I tried using \d+ without the g after the expression, and it only matched the first number in the string.

Basically, whether I use \d or \d+, as long as I have the g after the expression, It will find all of the numbers. So my question is, what is the difference between the two?

```
// Setup
  var testString = "There are 3 cats but 4 dogs.";

  var expression = /\d+/g;
  var digitCount = testString.match(expression).length;
```

Comment: `\d` = a single digit, `\d+` = at least one digit. `"22".match(/\d/g)` -> `Array [ "2", "2" ]`, but `"22".match(/\d+/g)` -> `Array [ "22" ]`

Comment: try using the test string "There are 3 cats but 41 dogs." and you will see the difference

Comment: Ohh, I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `g` at the end means `global`, ie. that you want to search for all occurrences. Without it, you'll just get the first match.

`\d`, as you know, means a single digit. You can add quantifiers to specify whether you want to match all the following, or a certain amount of digits afterwards.

`\d` means a single digit

`\d+` means all sequential digits

So let's say we have a string like this:

```
123 456
7890123
```

`/\d/g` will match `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3]`

`/\d/` will match `1`

`/\d+/` will match `123`

`/\d+/g` will match `[123,456,7890123]`

You could also use `/\d{1,3}/g` to say you want to match all occurrences where there are from 1 to 3 digits in a sequence.

Another common quantifier is the star symbol, which means 0 or more. For example `/1\d*/g` would match all sequences of digits that start with 1, and have 0 or more digits after it.

Answer (score 3):

Counting the occurrences of `\d` will find the number of *digits* in the string.

Counting the occurrences of `\d+` will find the number of *integers* in the string.

I.E.

```
123 456 789
```

Has 9 *digits*, but 3 *integers*.

Comment: Couldn't the term *numbers* be a bit misleading, when parsing a float like 3.14 it will be considered two numbers. It's technically true that it consists of two numbers I think it's preferable to explain what the `+` does in regex syntax.

Comment: @kb. From their question, I think they understand the syntax part from their lesson and from experimentation, they are just curious about how they are different in usage. I would think some hand-waving is allowable with the semantics as long as it makes sense to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`\d` means any digit from 0 to 9, the `+` says "one or more times".

As long as your numbers are single digit there is no difference, but in the string "I have 23 cows" and `\d` would match 2 alone whereas `\d+` would match 23.