# Struggle to find correct html-tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

## Task

Writing a crawler that outputs: Title, Artikelnummer, Price, Delivery Status in a .csv

https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm

***Problem***
It´s really hard to figure out, which html-tag on that webpage contains the information i need.
For example: `<small>Artikelnummer:&nbsp;001</small>`
How do i collect the 001?
There are several more tags, i do not clearly understand to get the info of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will select the node where the text you want is:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()')
```

Now, to catch only part of the return you can use regex. Fortunately [Scrapy selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) supports builtin regex. So you can use like this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').re_first(r'\d+')
```

or for a list with all results:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').re(r'\d+')
```

Comment: after running ```response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').re_first(r'\d+')``` i get following errormsg: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're_first' although i imported "re"

Comment: You don't need to `import re`, because this is a method from Scrapy and not from the `re` module. Are you sure you are using that **exact line of code**? Because from the error it seems like you are using `.get()` before the `.re_first()`. The get method will return a str and cause an `AttributeError` because you need a Scrapy selector to use `re_first` method.

Comment: oh damn, you are totally right! thanks at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Each ArtikelNummer is within

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()')
```

Is where they sit. You may be getting confused with the `<div class="signal_image status-2"> <i>` which is downstream of the div with class delivery status.

By the structure of the HTML you'll probably be wanting to select each card and do something like this.

```
card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center artikelbox"]')
for a in card:
    a.xpath('.//div[@class="delivery-status"]/small/text()').re_first(r'\d+')
```

Here the regex `\d+` searches only for digits sequentially. We use r'' because \ is an escape character which isn't recognised when it's in a string, but with the r we treat the string as raw string and it recognises the \ character.

Regex is a great way to getting specific parts of the text which are more complicated than what the string methods can do for you. It's useful to have a cursory understanding of it and so you can have a go at some basic ones and look up how to get what you want.

### Resources

[Regex and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110419/is-there-a-difference-between-d-and-d)

[Re Module | Python Module of the Week](https://pymotw.com/2/re/)

[Community StackOverflow Answer for Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)